# OpenGL C++ low level billboard/sprite of radial gradient color circle

Tags: c++, opengl, sprite

I am trying to create a billboard in my scene. The purpose is to put a circle with a radial gradient color (Atmosphere effect) cutting a sphere (Planet Earth) and always facing the camera so it gives the atmospheric effect but it does not cover the planet surface. (It displays the gradient color just around the sphere from the camera point of view.

I tried many different approaches without getting a good result (not able to use external libraries):

- Tutorial: (http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/ ) I found out this tutorial but it lacks implementation details and trying to adapt the code I always get compiling errors.
- glBitmap: it is used in my application to display text billboards, I imagine that I can create a bitmap representing the gradient and then display it but I don't know if the facing to camera is automatically managed and how to define that bitmap.
- GL_POLYGON: My first idea and maybe best practice, a polygon or quad with a texture containing the gradient and rotate it manually at each frame depending on the camera position.

Is there an easy way? can someone help me with one of these possibilities?

EDIT:

I forgot one thing I tried: I created a parallel orthographic view where I can put 2D stuff always facing the camera but when I try to put the Z to different values in order to hide it behind the planet, it completely disappears. I can only display it on top of the 3D scene.

Comment: `glBitmap` definitely is not going to do what you want. A gradient implies multiple shades, but a bitmap as GL uses the term, is a monochrome binary image. In other words, it's either full bright or full dark (the color can be changed based on state).

Comment: I was thinking more to use a bitmap to debine transparency or color for each pixel of the gradient. In fact I don't need two colors but one color and transparent.

Comment: Oh, okay. You could achieve that using blending, but `glBitmap` is deprecated and relies on raster position (which is also deprecated). Your best bet for doing this portably will involve shaders and/or the stencil buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the stencil buffer documentation, this project is all deprecated, that is the problem, working in 3D like in the 90's

Answer (score 1):

To "hide" the inner part of the atmospheric circle, you can use several methods :

use stencil buffer (write to stencil while rendering your planet, then use it to render atmosphere)

discard fragments in you fragment shader when the distance to planet center is less than planet radius

Forget about GL_POLYGON, is it deprecated

Comment: This is for the quad solution? I didn't know about stencil buffer, I will read about it, thanks.